# How can I get vim to return to normal tab display?

Tags: vim

In an effort to get vim to show vertical indentation lines I ran the following command:

```
:set list lcs=tab:\|\
```

Now my tabs look like this:

[image]

How can I reset vim to default behaviour of not displaying anything for tab characters?

Comment: `:set nolist` and then `:help listchars`...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just undo your changed option values: `'list'` is a boolean flag whose inverse is `'nolist'`. With your messed up value of `'listchars'`, you can reset it to the default by appending `&` (cp. `:help :set-default`):

```
:set nolist lcs&
```

Just restarting Vim also works :-)

Comment: I didn't know you could use an ampersand to reset an option to its default value. Thanks!